# Going from TestFlight to AppStore

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, appstore-approval

I have an app on TestFlight that is on version 2 (0.1.15). I want to submit this version to the AppStore to review to publish.

When I go to the "App Store" tab, the app that is listed as "Prepare for submission" is listed as version "iOS App 1.0".

Is this because when I push my app to the AppStore, it will start on v 1.0? Or is it not picking up on my V2 in TestFlight?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default version number.

> When you create a new app or platform the version number will always
> default to 1.0, but this can be changed before you submit the app for
> review.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/50931

Comment: thank you @zvi. follow up question, if I want the version to be "1" for the users in the app store but I want the code from version 2.0.15 from TestFlight to be what is pushed, is this possible? What I am trying to achieve is not push for the first time to the app store version 10 of the app, i think that would look weird to the users.